# Trouble with a sequential search algorithm

Tags: c, sequential

Also why does this give me an error because I used bool?

I need to use this sequential search algorithm, but I am not really sure how. I need to use it with an array. Can someone point me in the correct direction or something on how to use this.

```
bool seqSearch (int list[], int last, int target, int* locn){
     int looker;

     looker = 0;
     while(looker < last && target != list[looker]){
                  looker++;
     }

     *locn = looker;
     return(target == list[looker]);
}
```

Comment: I know I need to pass in the array and the size of the array for last, but I am not sure what to put in target and int* locn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'd use it like this...

```
// I assume you've set an int list[], an int listlen and an int intToFind

int where;
bool found = seqSearch(list, listlen - 1, intToFind, &where);
if (found)
{
    // list[where] is the entry that was found; do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>There are a few issues.</s>

1. I would change the name of last to size.
2. If you don't find the value, you will dereference an invalid memory location.

EDIT: I guess last is the `length - 1`.  That's an unusual signature. So the call is something like:

```
int list[CONSTANT];
...
int foundIndex;
bool found = seqSearch(list, sizeof(list)/sizeof(int), target, &foundIndex);
```

There are many ways to enable bool.  One is to use [`stdbool.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdbool.h) with C99.

Comment: This is straight out of the book. He said this might be on the final and I want to make sure I know how to use it

Comment: I agree with 2, but that's pretty standard C though, the responsibility of allocating the storage for `*locn` is that of the caller

Comment: hhafez, I think we both misunderstood. :)  I thought `last` was the length of the array (it's apparently the `length - 1`), so it seemed like the element after the array could be illegally accessed.  I was not talking about `locn`.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear

`list[]` is the list you are searching
`last` is the last index in the `list` 
`target` is what you are searching in `list`
`locn`  will contain the index at which `target` was found
the return value is a boolean indicating if the `target` was found

for your question how to pass locn, do something like

```
int locn; /* the locn where the index of target will be stored if found */

bool target_found = seqSearch(blah blah blah, &locn);
```

Comment: But what do I pass into locn?

Comment: 'int locn; /* the locn where the index of target will be stored if found */

bool target_found = seqSearch(blah blah blah, &locn);'

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is if you search for an element not present in the array, `looker` will be equal to `last` and you try to access an array element at location `last` which is invalid.

Instead you can do:

```
bool seqSearch (int list[], int last, int target, int* locn) { 

    int looker;

    for(looker=0;looker<last;looker++) {

        // target found.
        if(list[looker] == target) {
            *locn = looker; // copy location.
            return true;    // return true.
        }
    }

    // target not found.
    *locn = -1;   // copy an invalid location.
    return false; // return false.
}
```

You call the function as follows:

```
int list[] = {5,4,3,2,1}; // the array to search in.
int size = sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); // number of elements in the array.
int target = 3; // the key to search for.
int locn; // to hold the location of the key found..and -1 if not found.

if( seqSearch(list,size,target,&locn) ) {
  // target found in list at location locn.
} else {
  // target not found in list.
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `last` isn't in the array? You could pass in the length - 1 for `last` and then it functions just fine. I think `last` here just refers to the fact that it's the last place you should check (if you only want to check part of an array for example), and that the responsibility for providing the correct endpoint falls on the caller.

Comment: I am trying it like this, but it is giving me an error for using bool.

Comment: @shinjuo: You need to include `stdbool.h` here is a working example: http://www.ideone.com/pWmTx

Comment: @unicornadict: stdbool.h is actually the answer that the question was asking for.  You should repost as an answer.